# Html CSS align text inside div to numbers

Tags: html, css

Not entirely sure how to ask this specific question but here's what I'm trying to do.

Issue:

I have a table of questions and answer options:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div style="display: inline;">1. </div> <div style="display: inline;">asdf asdf asasdf <br/> asdf asdf </div></td>
      <td>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want the question to be displayed in the format of:

1. asdfasdf asd ad 
   asdf asdf asdf

What I'm getting is:

[image]

The br tags there to simulate when a question gets too long and the text wraps underneath. As you can see when that happens it wraps underneath the 1. I want it so that the text wraps in the format above.

I can get this to work by putting an ordered list inside the table data but that seems really hacky, I'm sure there's a more "proper" way to achieve what I want.

The ordered list version that I tried:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><ol><li value="1">asdf asdf asdf <br/> asdf asdf</li></ol></td>
      <td>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not exactly an expert in CSS so any help would be appreciated, I have no idea what to even search online for this as I'm not even sure what the proper term is to get something like this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a class instead of inline style. Just make number and text div `inline-block` so it will occupy the same height and text will not go below the number. 
Also added a class for td for keeping text vertically on top.

```css
.number, .text {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
  
td {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="number">1. </div> <div class="text">asdf asdf asasdf <br/> asdf asdf </div></td>
      <td>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as this was the first one and seems to be the cleanest and simplest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-1 (as per your requirement)**

with the below style, you will achieve the requirement. inline only makes the element to be in a line while it does not obey the height and width. Thus with the help of inline-block, we can get both the block and inline behavior.

```
.numbers,.row-data{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.numbers{
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

**code-1**

```css
table{
  width:50vw;
  margin:auto;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table .table-header{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:8px;
  
}
td{
  padding:10px;
}
.numbers,.row-data{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.numbers{
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <div  class='numbers'>1. </div> 
        <div class='row-data'>asdf asdf asasdf <br/> asdf asdf </div>         </td>
      
     <td>Yes Or No</td>
   
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Answer-2 (little modifications)**

Please refer to the below code. [codepen link](https://codepen.io/teddcp/pen/dyYvQLR?editors=1101)

```css
table{
  width:50vw;
  margin:auto;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table .table-header{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:8px;
  
}
td{
  padding:10px;
}
.row-numbering{
  min-width:15px;
  text-align:center;
}
.question{
  width:60%;
}
.answer{
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr class='table-header'>
     <th class='row-numbering'></th>
      <th class='question'>Question</th>
      <th class='answer'>Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class='row-numbering'>1</td>
      <td class='question'>
        asdf asdf asasdf <br/>asdf asdf asdf
     </td>
      <td class='answer'>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class='row-numbering'>2</td>
      <td class='question'>
        asdf asdf asasdf <br/>bsdf asdf asdf
     </td>
      <td class='answer'>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class='row-numbering'>3</td>
      <td class='question'>
        asdf asdf asasdf <br/>csdf asdf asdf
     </td>
      <td class='answer'>Yes Or No</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method: use `<ol>` (numbered list) inside your cell

It aligns the text with or without breaks.

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqupwgn2/1/)